# Simple PHP discord notification now respond with error code 50006

Tags: php, discord, webhooks, error-code

I have a simple daily PHP notification to a discord webhook. It was working for almost a year, but it's now responding me an error:

```
{"message": "Cannot send an empty message", "code": 50006}
```

`$content` is created before and filled, and it's not empty.
I replaced the real username and avatar link here.

```php
$hookObject = json_encode([
    "type" => "rich",
    "content" => "**Rotation today**\n\n".$content,
    "username" => "avatar",
    "avatar_url" => "link to avatar",
    "tts" => false,
], JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE );

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array( $ch, [
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $hookObject,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "Length" => strlen( $hookObject ),
        "Content-Type" => "application/json"
    ]
]);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
curl_close( $ch );
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem now?

Comment: I think you might not be talking about a webhook here, but about making an API call _from_ your app? But then the details are still very much unclear. The very least you should do here, is tells us what $url contains, and where we can find the documentation for that endpoint.

Comment: Btw., sure about the header named just `Length` …? Usual practice would be to use `Content-Length`.

Comment: I send $content to this URL:
$url = "https://discordapp.com/api/webhooks/463967713669414914/QvCyh5cCC5QaCNJI8TU0ovTvyFJ0FAojM0fpaPg4Fa-GrEw9wnASrW0iCwN3z3fv1KWC";

Comment: I changed to Content-Length, but the error still occurs.

Comment: And where is the documentation for that endpoint?

Comment: Maybe this?
https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro

Comment: I am not going to go through all of that now, to try and figure out what exactly you are trying to do here. Link to the specific section that explains how to perform whatever specific action it is you are trying to perform here.

Comment: Sorry.
I think its this one: https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/webhook

I want to send the message to a discord channel on my discord server.

Comment: Code castling and general formatting

Comment: Problem is not solved. Does nobody has an idea?

Comment: I had the very same error and in my case it was adding explicit "Content-type: application/json" header that helped (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022027/discord-webhook-message-cannnot-send) question). Are you sure your header is passed correctly?

Comment: How can i check this, @adamczi?

Comment: I would make the very same request to some [request bin](http://requestbin.net) instead of your target address. When you make a request there it shows you all the details including headers

Comment: This is the result:
HEADERS
Cf-Ipcountry: DE

Content-Length: 267

Cf-Connecting-Ip: 85.13.132.137

Total-Route-Time: 0

X-Request-Id: 37815d14-d098-45b4-b23f-53930e1b347e

Cdn-Loop: cloudflare

Connection: close

X-Forwarded-Proto: http

Accept: */*

Cf-Ray: 53d405d2da4cd44f-HAM

X-Request-Start: 1575024648310

Connect-Time: 0

X-Forwarded-For: 85.13.132.137, 162.158.202.180

X-Forwarded-Port: 80

Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Accept-Encoding: gzip

Host: requestbin.net

Via: 1.1 vegur

Cf-Visitor: {"scheme":"http"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also got this error last day. 
I found this code and it works:

```
//===========================================
// Create new webhook in your Discord channel settings and copy&paste URL
//===========================================
$webhookurl = "YOUR_WEBHOOK_URL";

//===========================================
// Compose message. You can use Markdown
// Message Formatting -- https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/reference#message-    formatting
//===========================================
$msg = "Test **message** ";
$json_data = array ('content'=>"$msg");
$make_json = json_encode($json_data);
$ch = curl_init( $webhookurl );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $make_json);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```